# Set Value to the next row in the same column on subsequent script run, Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-forms, setvalue

I have this javascript code that is supposed to set a value **Yes** or **No** to a cell and subsequently move to the next cell in the same row when the script is run again.

I have tried it severally but only sets the value to the current cell but doesn't move to the next row in the same column. Anyone with an idea on how to do it?

Here is the code.

```
function lastRowData(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() 
 var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn()
 var lastRowData = sheet.getRange(lastRow,1,1,lastCol).getValues()
 return lastRowData[0]
}
function myFunction() {
var lastRow = lastRowData()
var data = {

    'name':lastRow[2],
    'client': lastRow[3],
    'starts_at':lastRow[5],
    'ends_at':lastRow[6],
    'project_state':lastRow[4],
};
var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    'payload' : data,

};
var url = 'https:...auth=token';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) { 
        sheet.getRange("X" + lastRow).setValue("Yes");
    }
    else {
        sheet.getRange("X" +  lastRow ).setValue("No");
    }
    Logger.log(response);
   return response.getContentText();
}
```

Comment: check what lastRow value is, seems like the value is not getting updated...

Comment: Hi @Icewine, I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but the last value is successfully set/updated in the first cell, only that it cannot move to the next cell when I run the script again.

Comment: I mean that the variable lastRow is not being updated. Since you only put a tiny bit of your code here, i am guessing you did this: var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); Without the rest of your code it will be a little difficult to help you.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have edited my code so that you can view the complete version. Thanks